# SQL / PHP SELECT everything if condition is not met

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an input on my webpage with two search parameters (e.g. type and location). When the parameters are inputted, PHP searches the SQL database and outputs the results which satisfy the input parameters.

```
$sql = "
SELECT MainID
     , MainName
     , MainLocation
     , MainType 
  FROM Main 
 WHERE MainType = 'typeIWant' 
   AND MainLocation = 'LocationIWant' 
";
```

However, when the user selects only one parameter it should display all the results that satisfy only the selected parameter.

Something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT MainID, MainName, MainLocation, MainType FROM Main WHERE MainType= 'typeIWant' AND MainLocation = '*' ";
```

Except this doesn't work.

It should display all the results that satisfy MainType regardless of what their MainLocation is.

How is this done?

Comment: Remove `AND MainLocation = '*'` from your second query.

Comment: But I have an input that takes in two parameters, so if the user just wants to search by one parameter what do I put in the second parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `if statement` to check that for example:

```
$sql = "
SELECT MainID
     , MainName
     , MainLocation
     , MainType 
  FROM Main 
 WHERE MainType = 'typeIWant'  
";

if (isset($_GET['MainLocation']) && $_GET['MainLocation'] != '') {
  $sql .= " AND MainLocation = 'LocationIWant'"
}
```

Comment: EDIT: if anyone else wants to use the code just add  a semicolon after
$sql .= " AND MainLocation = 'LocationIWant'";

Answer (score 2):

The below line:

```
$sql = "SELECT MainID, MainName, MainLocation, MainType FROM Main WHERE MainType= 'typeIWant' AND MainLocation = '*' ";
```

Is searching for a `MainLocation` called (or named as ) `*`

If you want to search only on `MainType` you should just do:

```
$sql = "SELECT MainID, MainName, MainLocation, MainType FROM Main WHERE MainType= 'typeIWant' ";
```

Comment: I have an input that takes in two parameters, so it works fine if the user wants to filter the results using two parameters, but what if the user just wants to search by one parameter what do I put in the second parameter?